# How to create notification for success application deployment in ECS Docker?

Tags: docker, notifications, amazon-ecs

I have a PHP web-based-application deployed in ECS Docker Container. I use travis for deploying application to ECS. It's nice to have (slack) notification once the application deployed successfully in docker.

EC2 instance deployment notification (via Auto-Scaling Group - SNS) is not enough, because it still need several minutes process in docker.

The idea may be just like this  [https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-slack-integration-blueprints-for-aws-lambda/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efZGA.png)

Just change Auto Scaling group to **Docker**.

But I have no idea how to get this done.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: how did you deploy the application?
by console, aws cli or sothing like code deploy or jenkins?

Comment: using python sdk boto